# SyntaxError with psycopg2 using function dense_rank

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to launch a query to a database through Python, with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import psycopg2
import pandas.io.sql as sqlio

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="000.00.00", database="xxx", user="xxx", password="xxx")

query = "select c_code, 
       a_code, 
       price, 
       quantity, 
       weight, 
       dense_rank() over(partition by a_code order by quantity) r_provv,        
       quantity*weight as q_x_w
       from tran_tab"


df = sqlio.read_sql(query, conn)
conn = None
```

But I get the following SyntaxError message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ago\Desktop\prova\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1586, in execute
    cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ... 'quantity, '         'weight, '         'dense_rank() (over(p...
                                                               ^
```

Comment: Hello Agostino, welcome to Stack Overflow. Which database are you running this query against: mysql, sqlite, ...? Please add the relevant tag to your question. Also, please provide the version of the database (MySQL 8.0, SQLite 3.16, ...).

Comment: @GMB `psycopg2` is PostGreSQL.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks. This query looks like valid Postgresql to me.

Comment: @GMB I don't use PostGreSQL, but I looked up the documentation and window functions have been available for a long time, he'd have to be using a prehistoric version.

Comment: I don't think this is your actual code, since you can't write a multi-line string literal like that in Python. You should either put a backslash at the end of each line that needs continuation, or you should enclose the string literal in triple quotes. Please update your question with your actual code.